# How Can I Do Create Table by using sql query in NHibernate?

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a dynamic table in my project, I doing mapping static table by using Nhibernate fluent API in the model solution. Dynamic table going to create at runtime. dynamic tables have dynamic columns. How can I do Create a dynamic table in NHibernate? thanks for help

```
 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Events](
        [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [Name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [StartDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
        [EndDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
        [Quota] [int] NOT NULL,
        [Description] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Events] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [Id] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/querysql.html

Answer (score 0):

thanks for help. 
I was already using Isession.CreateSqlQuery(sql) but not was working Create table 
improved when replace code ' Isession.createSqlQuery(sql).executeUpdate()'